# How to docker run an API project pointing to same port with two GitHub branches simultaneously

Tags: docker

I need to run Job 1 and Job 2 at the same time. The local API project is same repository in both the cases but it should have different GitHub branch.

Job details:

- Job 1 - Running Local API project by `make serviceup`. This job runs Postman collection tests
- Job 2 - Running Local API project by `make serviceup`. This job has a web app UI tests (not a Docker project) dependant on this local API project

Note that Postman (for job 1) and the UI tests (for job 2) are run on the host, and are not themselves containerized.

I'm new to containerization and have read about it but seems I'm having issues setting it up. Here I even don't know if containerization is the answer. How can I set it up so that I can run jobs simultaneously?

If I run both jobs simultaneously with the setup I have then it throws an error that the `Bind for 0.0.0.0:XXXX failed: port is already allocated` which I expect.

Comment: Are you running Postman (for job 1) and UI tests (for job 2) on the Docker host (or planning to)?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is I'm not able to make the service run for the 2 jobs at the same time as it points to the same port. There are so many dependant project of my local API project so I don't want to change the port of my project.

Comment: Sure, I understand your core problem. I was confirming something that was not clear, so that I do not give incorrect advice. My next question is, why are you running the two services on the same port? You can use the `-p` flag in `docker run` to specify different ports - use `8080` for the first one, and `8081` for the second one.